# A good way to utilize javascript to download files in batches to prevent browser time out

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So to start, I am using the fancybox library here.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

My end goal is to create a photoalbum that downloads images stored on Amazon S3 via Cloudfront. Right now it is setup to where there is a main page and each page has a single image. Click that image and it opens an album.

The problem is that if my album has 75 items or whatever large amount, the browser will timeout and crash or cause my computer to run out of memory (I am running this locally as I dev it).

here is some sample code

```js
function photoDL(){
  var num = 0;
  var batch = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 62; i++){
    var myphoto = 'https://MYCODEFRONTSTUFF/'+i+'.jpg';
    var albumpic = new Array();
    albumpic.push(myphoto);

    for(batch = 1; batch < 5; batch++){
      $.fancybox.open([
        {
          src  : albumpic[num],
          opts : {
            caption : 'First caption'
          }
        },
      ], {
        loop : false,
        hash : "album3"
      });
      setTimeout(photoDL(), 10000);
      num += 1;



    }


  }
}
```

I know there is some stuff in there that doesn't look right. I was thinking I could set the SetTimeout to buffer and give it some time to download each image but that didn't help. It still tries to download them all at once. I was playing with the idea of creating batches but hit a deadend. Any help is greatly appreciatd.

Comment: If your browser fails to load 75 images before crashing then there's something wrong - what size are the images?

Comment: between 1-2MB/image

Answer (score 0):

Your code loops 61 time and inside each of the loop, you have inner loop that runs 5 times. And inside each inner loop - you open new fancyBox instance (over the existing one) and then you call main loop!

So, you open fancyBox 243 times and after 10000ms you open 58,806 new instances and you are wondering why your browser crashes? :)

Comment: This is just the latest iteration. The original code had no loops and I am admittedly newer to JS/jQuery so apologize for the confusion and ignorance on my part. 

What would be a better execution method?

Comment: I do not understand how downloading and opening fancybox manually is related. So, you just wanted to create group of images and simply display them in fancyBox? Then your updated code looks fine.

Comment: Thanks. I was making a world of n00b mistakes, I acknowledge it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the insights, I did manage to figure this one out. Introducing the fixed code

```js
function photoDL(batch, url, ftype){
  var num = 0;
  var fArr = [];
  var albumpic = new Array();
  var fboxOpen = '';
  for(i = 1; i < batch; i++){
  var myphoto = url+i+ftype;
  albumpic[i] = myphoto;
  //console.log(albumpic[i]);
  var fboxOpen =
    {
      src  : albumpic[i],
      opts : {
        caption : 'First caption'
      }
    };
  fArr[i] = fboxOpen;

  }
  fArr.shift();
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(fArr);
  console.log(jsonString);


  $.fancybox.open(
    fArr
    , {
      loop : false,
      hash : "album3"
    });
  }
```

A little slow but it's definitely working!